# Using multiple variables while loop bash

Tags: bash, scripting

Looking for some help on writing a bash script with command that call multiple variables where each variable contains list of text that needs file to run against

Here is my example.

file1.txt:

```
USA
EU
Asia
SouthAmerica
```

file2.txt:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

```
var1=$(cat file1.txt)
var2=$(cat file2.txt)

echo $var1
USA EU Asia SouthAmerica

echo $var2
user1 user2 user3 user4
```

What I need is for

```
while read var1 var2;
do
   *command* --region $var1 --profile $var2 *do something*;

done | tee -a $var2.txt
```

How can I get the one command to iterate through contents of `var1` and `var2` to produce the results I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a couple of for loops:

```
var1=$(cat file1.txt)
var2=$(cat file2.txt)
for i in ${var1} ; do
  for x in ${var2} ; do
    *command* --region ${i} --profile ${x} *do something*
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you want to achieve. If you want to execute the command for each user in each region you can use two nested while loops:

```
while read -r region ; do
    while read -r user ; do
        command --region "${region}" --profile "${user}"
    done < users.txt
done < regions.txt
```

Btw, the `read` builtin works different that you might assume. Check `help read` to see how it works.